# Inline-block element not positioning after other inline-block element

Tags: html, css

I have two `inline-block` elements. Both are 50% width. Let's call them left and right div.

The right `inline-block` element is a combination of two different images. The thing is only one image shows at a time because I have one of the two set to `display:none;`. One of the images shows at 1000px - 1400px viewport. The thing is, that image doesn't appear right after the left div. It is doing this:

[image]

The image that is in every other viewport other than 1000 - 1400 works fine.

This should look like  this:

[image]

Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fbc0y3qs/)

The images (div) in question is

```
company-information-block2-2
```

Comment: Try to add float:left to .section-blocks

Answer (score 3):

You have given each of those elements a width of 50%.

```
.section-blocks {
  width: 50%;
  height: auto;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

In order for them to appear on the same line, there must be no space between them at all. Any extra space between the elements will bump the right element down to the next line.

In your jsFiddle there is a space between the two `.section-blocks` elements -- which bumps the image on the right down to the next line. If you eliminate the space, then they will sit together nicely on the same line.

Here's a working example:
**https://jsfiddle.net/fbc0y3qs/1/**

Where one tag ends, the other must immediately begin:

```
</div><div id="company-information-block2" class="section-blocks">
```

Applying a `float:left;` can also achieve the same end result, but it may have undesired effects on the widths of your elements. A `float:left;` changes more than just the positioning of the element.

Comment: I don't get where you see a space at? I already have the `.section-blocks` at 50% width.

Comment: @Becky If you take a look at your original code you will see that your second block `<div id="company-information-block2" class="section-blocks">` is on a new line. That new line creates the space. In my jsFiddle, I removed that new line and backed up the element so that it immediately begins after the first block ends. When you have both elements set to 50% width, there can't be any space between the two elements else they won't fit on the same line.

Comment: Gotcha. Thanks for the insight. If you are referring to the jsfiddle code, it must have been the tidy up feature that rearranged everything. In my actual code I do not have any spaces.

Answer (score 1):

it would be solved with `float`.

Try this i'm sure it helps.

```
.section-blocks {
    float: left;
}
```